# MPAndroidChart change font (Typeface)

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I was trying to change the font using Typeface but it doesn't work. Here is my code below

```
val tf = Typeface.createFromFile("app/src/main/res/font/montserrat_regular.ttf")
data.setValueTypeface(tf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
val tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "font/montserrat_regular.ttf")
data.setValueTypeface(tf)
```